# Replacing "// " with ";" using sed

Tags: windows, sed

I am trying to replace in a file all ocurrences of "// " (without quotes) for ";". For example, this is file.txt:

```
// this is a comment
hello.
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
;this is a comment
hello.
```

I have tried this with no success:

```
sed  s%//\s%;%g file.txt
```

I should say I am using the Windows port of the tool found here:
http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: `sed` doesn't support `\s`.

Comment: You tagged your question with both windows and unix - which is your question about?

Comment: Thanks you Ed Morton. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed "s,// ,;,g" filename
```

Does this work for you ?

Comment: Perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

UNIX assumed: Always quote scripts - `sed 'script'`, not `sed script`. As written the shell will interpret your `;` as the end of the command. Also, most seds will not recognize `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`. Use this:

```
$ sed 's#// #;#' file
;this is a comment
hello.
```

or this:

```
$ sed 's#//[[:space:]]#;#' file
;this is a comment
hello.
```

Comment: I'm afraid that the port that I'm using will display this when doing that:

    sed: -e expression #1, char 1: Unknown command: `''

Comment: As stated in the answer the above is UNIX syntax since you had originally tagged your question with UNIX. Idk what magical incantations are required to make anything work in Windows. My advice is that you install cygwin and run UNIX commands from that.